# Bootstrap (v3.1.1) modal not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked around at the various solutions but can't seem to get this working. I've used the following code to create a modal:

```
<div aria-hidden='true' aria-labelledby='newSpeakerLabel' class='modal fade speaker-form' role='dialog' tabindex='-1'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button aria-hidden='true' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' type='button'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='newSpeakerLabel'>New Speaker</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        Put the form here
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' type='button'>Close</button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Save Speaker</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Speakers</h1>
<div class='well bs-component'>
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Display each speaker -->
    <!-- Link that launches the modal -->
    <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' data-target='.speaker-form' data-toggle='modal'>Add speaker</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

When I click the "Add speaker" button, all that happens is that the page darkens as though the modal will appear but it never shows up. any ideas? Thanks! (Yes, I've added the bootstrap.min.js file).

Comment: Not 100% sure but does it maybe have to be activated via an ID rather than a class?

Comment: @BillyMoat I originally started with an ID and it doesn't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the dash in the `modal-content` class

Change

```
<div class='modal content'>
```

to...

```
<div class='modal-content'>
```